# Typing "danger" not working in google chrome anymore

Tags: google-chrome, https

Some https sites dont work in chrome.
In prev versions you could type "danger" to open the site, now it doesn't work anymore

Anyone knows why

Comment: As an aside, be _very_very_ sure you want to open such sites. This indicates a very serious problem.

Comment: @chromesux If my answer is acceptable, please mark it as answered. Thank you.

Comment: yea, it indicates a serious problem with chrome: it sucks.

Comment: -1: The new code is "badidea" for a reason. What you're asking for *is* a bad idea.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Febuary of 2016, the over-ride code changed to 'badidea' and it is part of the Chromium base that Chrome is built in.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=581189

Comment: This is no longer accurate; see @sanmai's answer below for the current solution.

Answer (score 12):

In January 2018 the interstitial bypass keyword was changed to the output of...

```
window.atob('dGhpc2lzdW5zYWZl');
```

If you can't type this into a console, probably you should not use it.

It will be changed again in the future. If so, [refer to the source code](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/components/security_interstitials/core/browser/resources/interstitial_large.js).

Comment: The keyword is `thisisunsafe`.